# Automatically resize WPF Grid Column

Tags: wpf, grid

I have a WPF Application, which contains Grid Element with two columns.
The second column also contains grid element.
I have a timer and after 5 seconds the second grid's visibility becomes collapsed, but first column doesn't resize.

It is possible to automatically resize first column ( to fit the whole window after setting second grid's visibility to collapsed?

```
-----------------------|
|               |      |
|               |grid2 |
|               |      |
|               |      |
|--------------------- |


<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <!-- Browser -->
        <my:WebControl Visibility="{Binding IsIEVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleconverter}}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="webControl1">

        </my:WebControl>

        <GridSplitter Visibility="{Binding isVisiblePult, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleconverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Grid Visibility="{Binding isVisiblePult, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleconverter}}" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListBox x:Name="ListChannels" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChannel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}" FontSize="14" Background="#FFD4ECFF">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="17" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the second and third column definitions "Auto", then set explicit widths on your grid splitter and second Grid. Then when you collapse them the main grid will behave as you require